# struct EMPLOYEE {...} em1,em2; or struct EMPLOYEE {...};

Tags: c, struct

Are these two the same?

```
struct EMPLOYEE {
...
};

int main (void)
{
    //Local Declaration
    struct EMPLOYEE em1;
    struct EMPLOYEE em2;
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
struct EMPLOYEE {
...
}em1,em2;
```

If I use the latter case, is it not necessary for me to declare those structures in the main function as I did in the former case?

Comment: In the latter case, the two are globals.

Comment: And in the first case they are locals

Comment: That sums it up pretty much Thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer I have an extra question. What should I do if I want to declare like the latter with `typedef struct`? where do I put my em1, em2

Answer (score 2):

```
struct EMPLOYEE {
...
};
```

defines a structure called EMPLOYEE but otherwise does not create any instances.

```
struct EMPLOYEE {
...
}em1,em2;
```

defines the structure EMPLOYEE and creates two instances called `em1` and `em2`.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
struct EMPLOYEE {
...
}em1,em2;
```

you could then use them in the main the following way

```
int main (void)
{
    em1.memberx = 2; /*assuming memberx is a member of your structure.*/
    return 0;
}
```

else you would have to declare them like you did in your main function example.

You have another option doing it like this:

```
typedef struct
{
...
}EMPLOYEE;
```

and then declare them like this :

```
EMPLOYEE em1;
EMPLOYEE em2;
```

and use them like this in your main also :

```
int main (void)
    {
        em1.memberx = 2; /*assuming memberx is a member of your structure.*/
        return 0;
    }
```